# AJAX request not working when using HTTPS in Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, safari

I'm not a big expert in ajax, but my request is pretty straightforward:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://62.72.93.18/index.php?a=get_lights",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (res) {
        notify ? jsonLightsDone(res) : jsonLights(res)
    }
});
```

The code works without problem on Chrome, but on Safari it only works if I change from https to http.

I think it may have to do with the ssl certificate on the server that I created with openssl, but I'm leaning myself into territory I really know nothing about. 
 How can I fix this?

Edit:

The javascript console outputs:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Das Zertifikat für diesen Server ist ungültig. Möglicherweise wirst du mit einem Server verbunden, der vorgibt, „62.72.93.18“ zu sein, und der deine vertraulichen Daten gefährdet. (index.php, line 0)
```

I'm sorry, I can't change the language to English, but it says it can't connect because the certificate is not valid, as Gimo pointed out.

Comment: do you have any javascript console output?

Comment: I uploaded the console output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ssl certificate is not valid.

Comment: Can I do anything about that without a huge effort?

Comment: use letsencrypt.org. its a free ssl certifcate or make your request without https :).